# Cut image by specific shapefile using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

#### Background

I have tried to download terrain map from DEMIS server using Python language.

The code I wrote was listed below:

```
## Downloding terrain image of Northeastern Asia
llx,lly, urx,ury = [102,25,147,57]    
target = 'http://www2.demis.nl/wms/wms.asp?Service=WMS&WMS=worldmap&Version=1.1.0&Request=GetMap&BBox=%s,%s,%s,%s'%(llx,lly, urx,ury) +\
         '&SRS=EPSG:4326&Width=1600&Height=1200&Layers=Bathymetry,Countries,Topography,Ocean%20features,Hillshading,Borders,Waterbodies,Coastlines&Format=image/gif'
path_name = './INPUT/Northeastern_Asia.gif'
urllib.urlretrieve(target, path_name)
```

Then I can show it with Matplotlib.Basemap
[image]

#### Idea

The code above gives a easy way to get the terrain map for specific square space with pre-determined corner locations.

If I want to cut the original figure by a shapefile within it (outlined in red), is it possible to achieve in Python?

[image]

I have uploaded the original image and the shapefile of the target area. If you are interested, any advices are appreciated.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you provided a [mcve] of the issue. I.e. a code that can be run and changed to show the solution.

Comment: So what you want is to obtain a raster resulting with only the area delimited by the shapefile? This can be done in QGis directly easier than with code, is that what you seek?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to obtain the figure only within a specific shapefile. Thanks for your comments, I''ll try to use QGIS instead.